# Is there a program development environment similar to Visual studios?

Tags: development-environment

I'm getting really tired of working against click-once and I'm wondering if there's a better alternative. I'm looking for a programming environment that preferably does not depend on the .net framework. I'm not sure how much .net does for me exactly (though I have some idea) but I'd like to make my programs as independent of downloading a microsoft or other framework. I often think of professional programs like itunes, gimp or firefox that don't require someone to have a .net framwork. I'd also like to have these programs work on windows mac and linux. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I feel like I'll look at Qt, get more serious about learning java and web development. I was afraid that I wouldn't be able to find a similar environment. I guess it's time to post new questions on how to deal with these .NET issues....and clickonce....wohoo....lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C or C++.

If you're looking to make a program that is like gimp or Firefox, than you'll have no other good alternative. Java needs its virtual machine and web apps require an Internet connection. Though that's rarely a problem these days, it simply might not be applicable in your case. However, like the others have alluded, true platform-independence is tricky and that is certainly not less trivial in C or C++. That's pretty much why Java and .NET came to be in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [Qt and QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products). QtCreator supports integration with Visual Studio, so you can continue to use the environment you apparently already like, but still produce portable results.

Answer (score 2):

You could always write your applications in Java, using the Eclipse or Netbeans IDE. Java is cross-platform so that takes care of Linux and Mac.

Alternatively, you could write your code in C or C++, and use a separate compiler for each platform. But that is more difficult because it will expose you to more (all?) of the differences in the three platforms.

Answer (score 1):

What about a web app, should work on all devices. Otherwise you can use Java but then people need to have Java on their machine. Native code will be a pain in the neck sicne you then need to compile it for all different OS versions

Comment: but then your framework is a browser...

Comment: But anyone who can find the app is all but guaranteed to have a web browser installed.  A Java VM, or the .net runtime, or a scripting language?  Not so much.